How to solve this invalid block issue after sending a Transaction?
I'm experiencing a strange issue: occasionally, I get an invalid block error after trying to submit an extrinsic in my node. I created a script that runs 300 transfer transactions sequentially, sending tokens from Alice to Bob. After a while, I confirmed that some transactions are invalid (2~8% roughly). When I console.log() them, they appear as invalid and empty. I'm using version 1.5 on a test net with three different parachains (one collator each) and three validators (one for each para). I'm not sure if I need to increase the number of collators or validators, or if this is a bug in this version.

Update:
Apparently, the issue is not with the transactions but with the block. Occasionally, a block is discarded. In this example, block number 656842 had just 3 events, whereas other blocks had more than 60.
When I click on the block details, I get an error message: 'Unable to decode block events. 4003: Client error. UnknownBlock: State already discarded for 0x73.....' Additionally, I observed a reorg event in the parachain logs one block before.




Are you waiting until the transactions are finalized? Otherwise they can be re-orged.
It is also a good idea to always pass in the signature nonce manually, and not rely on  what the node reports since that could be from a different temporary fork.

Thank you for taking some time to read the question. So, I ran several tests, sending without waiting for completion and sending one by one, only after the previous transaction was finished. In both cases, reorgs still happen on the parachain, and therefore, all extrinsics in that block are discarded and temporarily banned. I don't know what causes these constant reorgs, and I'm not sure if it’s normal to lose all the transactions within that block, but these reorgs always happen even when I'm not sending anything to the parachain. Any ideas?
